# protractor checking if element is selected

Tags: protractor

I have 3 buttons, the html is:

```
<label class="label-text btn btn-primary active ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" btn-radio="thisDateType.value" ng-model="controller.formData.dateType" value="disputeDate" name="dateType" ng-class="{active:thisDateType.id==controller.dateTypeSelect.radioModel.id}" ng-repeat="thisDateType in controller.dateTypeSelect.dateType">Dispute Date</label>
<!-- end ngRepeat: thisDateType in controller.dateTypeSelect.dateType -->
<label class="label-text btn btn-primary ng-dirty" btn-radio="thisDateType.value" ng-model="controller.formData.dateType" value="respondByDate" name="dateType" ng-class="{active:thisDateType.id==controller.dateTypeSelect.radioModel.id}" ng-repeat="thisDateType in controller.dateTypeSelect.dateType">Respond By Date</label>
<!-- end ngRepeat: thisDateType in controller.dateTypeSelect.dateType -->
<label class="label-text btn btn-primary" btn-radio="thisDateType.value" ng-model="controller.formData.dateType" value="slaDate" name="dateType" ng-class="{active:thisDateType.id==controller.dateTypeSelect.radioModel.id}" ng-repeat="thisDateType in controller.dateTypeSelect.dateType">SLA Date</label>
<!-- end ngRepeat: thisDateType in controller.dateTypeSelect.dateType -->
```

I'm trying to assert that the first button is selected using:

```
expect(SearchPage.disputeDateButton.isSelected()).toBe(true);
```

However protractor keeps evaluating that disputeDateButton.isSelected() is false. I've double checked my element locator xpath and its the correct one. Am I doing this right or is there another method that can be used?

Comment: Can you share the identifier for `SearchPage.disputeDateButton`.

Comment: These buttons are part of a library plugin. Because of that, I had to work with what was given. There was no way of specifically locating that element except by the array position that I have provided. You can use that method to identify disputeDateButton.

Answer (score 2):

```
element.all(by.repeater("thisDateType")).then(function(buttonArray) {
    expect(buttonArray[0].getAttribute('class')).toBe('label-text btn btn-primary active');
});
```

since the class value changes depending on what's selected, I decided to evaluate that instead and it works.